# How to middle-align text in \rhead?

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment

I have just started coding in `LaTeX` and it has been a big learning curve! As a result, I hope the detail I've added in this question will suffice.

I am attempting to produce an R Markdown report knitted to PDF. I have removed a lot of the title space as I don't want it, and instead have a header with a logo on the right-hand side and text on the left. I'm wondering how I can amend my code so I can get the `\rhead` text to be middle-aligned within the header section. Currently, it is positioned bottom-right of the header and I'd like it essentially middle-right.

In addition, how can I make the same header text bigger than `\LARGE`? I'd like it at least twice the size as what it is now. Thanks.

```
---
title: >
  `\vspace{-1.8cm}`{=latex}
header-includes: 
 - \usepackage{geometry}
 - \geometry{top=0.1in,left=0.1in,bottom=0.1in,right=0.1in}
 - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 - \pagestyle{fancy}
 - \fancyhf{}
 - \addtolength{\headheight}{3.0cm}
 - \rhead{\LARGE Middle Alignment of Header Text}
 - \lhead{\includegraphics[width=2.3cm]{Logo.png}}
 - \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
 - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
mainfont: SourceSansPro
output: pdf_document
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---
```

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{adjustbox}` and then use `\includegraphics[valign=c,...]{..}`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Werner. Please forgive me, but I am a complete novice with `LaTeX` and still very raw with understanding the language. Are you able to provide a specific example of how I'd use your recommended code with my `\rhead` line?

Comment: Look at the `header-includes` in [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/NzKi6cVT).